# Magento sends too many confirmation emails

Tags: php, magento

I have a Magento store that apparently sends too many confirmations emails on an order. My theory is that the emails are resent all over again to the store admin when the customer tries to shop entering an inexistent email address.

How can I debug and/or fix this?

Thanks

Comment: The first step would definitely be identifying at which point the confirmation mails get sent.

Comment: I've tested a bit and it seems that it happens only when customer's email address does not exist. It keeps sending the confirmation email to that invalid address and it also sends it to the store admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the customer's email getting returned to sender? If so try setting the sender address to a blackhole, a mailbox that drops all messages. It's not uncommon for sites to have a "noreply@" address for this purpose.